# Вычисление разницы времени в sql

Tags: sql

```
SELECT now() > '2018-10-30 20:15:25'
```

почему это выражение выдаёт `0`, т.е. `false` ?
по идее `now()` должно быть больше
проверяю в `openserver phpmyadmin`

Comment: Вы уже посмотрели, что выдаёт просто `now()`?

Comment: now() = 2018-10-30 22:03:31

Comment: или это сравнивается строка а не дата?

Comment: как тогда правильно сравнить дату?

Comment: У меня ваш изначальный вариант дает 1. проблема не воспроизводиться

Comment: Я в нем ничего криминального не вижу. любые подобные сравнения обычно работают без проблем. самое интересное, что оно должно было дать правильный результат даже если бы произвело сравнение строк

Comment: Из безумных предположений, только два: 1. конкретно phpmyadmin обрабатывает now() как то сам, не передавая его mysql. 2. mysql как то по особому работает с временной зоной при конвертации строки в дату-время (например переводит по временной зоне сервера, при том что при отображении now() в клиента переводит его в временную зону клиента)

Comment: А что вам дает `SELECT subdate('2018-10-30 20:15:25', 0)` ?

Comment: Отнимите еще несколько часов от второй даты, чтобы проверить вариант с timezone.

Comment: ок, вечером проверю, сейчас за другим пк